# Issue with Kannada Language Rendering in WordPress Tags and URLs

Tags: wordpress, url, utf-8, tags, kannada

I hope this email finds you well. I am writing to seek assistance with a Kannada language rendering issue I am facing on my WordPress website.

I have been attempting to use Kannada characters in my tags and URLs, but unfortunately, they are not rendering properly. The characters appear distorted, making the content difficult to read and understand.

To provide you with more context, here are a few examples of the Kannada characters I’m using: (ಆವಸಸಥನದ, ಇದರದ, ಉಷಣತ, ಕಕ, ಕಗಗಸತತದ, ಕಫ, ನಷಟವ, ಪರಗಸಪರಶಕ, ಬಳಗಳಗ, ಬಳಬಹದ, ಭರ, ಭವಷಯದಲಲ, ಮತತ, ಸಖಯಯನನ, ಹಡತ).

I have taken several steps to address this issue, including using Unicode fonts, ensuring UTF-8 character encoding, and customizing the permalink structure to include Kannada characters. However, the problem persists.

I have also tried deactivating plugins one by one to rule out any potential conflicts, and I have ensured that my WordPress installation is up to date. Despite these efforts, the rendering issue remains unresolved.

I am reaching out to the WordPress community for guidance on resolving this matter. If you or any of the forum members have experience with Kannada language rendering in WordPress and can provide insights or solutions, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

I believe that a correct rendering of Kannada characters is essential for the accessibility and readability of my website’s content, and I am committed to resolving this issue as soon as possible.

Thank you in advance for your support, and I look forward to your response.

I have tried a lot but have no clue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.